# solving an equation containing an complex integral

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I want to solve a numerical equation which include an integral. 
The problem parameters are : `w` (is a complex : `w = wr +I wi`), `k`(given parameter) and `z` (given parameter).

Then I want to find from the solution of my equation, the real (`wr`) and imaginary (`wi`) solutions as a function of `k` at given `z`.

My integral is defined as:

```
integral[w_?NumericQ,k_?NumericQ,z_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[((1-(4/z) 
Log[Sin[(Pi t)/2]])^3 (Sin[(Pi t)/2])^2 Sin[Pi t])/(z Sqrt[(1-(4/z) 
Log[Sin[(Pi t)/2]])^2-1]((1-(4/z) Log[Sin[(Pi t)/2]])^2((w^2/k^2)-1)+1)),{t,0,1},
MaxRecursion -> 200]
```

The equation to solve is defined as :

```
eq[w_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ,z_?NumericQ]:=1 + (z/k^2) (1 -
((Pi z Exp[-z] w^2 integral[w, k, z])/ (k^2 BesselK[1,z])))+I (Pi w z
Exp[-z/Sqrt[1 - (w^2/k^2)]])/(2 BesselK[1,z] (1 - (w^2/k^2))^(3/2) k^3)
```

To find the real solutions, I run :

```
wr[k,z]:=Re[w/.FindRoot[eq[w,k,z], {w,0.987}]];
```

And to find the imaginary solutions, I run :

```
wi[k,z]:=Im[w/.FindRoot[eq[w,k,z], {w,0.987}]];
```

In a another scientific paper, `wr` and `wi` are plotted as a function of `k` for a given`z`.

My problem is, when I set a value for `k` and `z`, I don't find the corresponding values of wr and wi as in the plot.

For example, from the plot, if `z = 100` and `k = 3` : `wr = 1.138`; `wi/wr = -0.0066`. However via my code, I find : `wr = 2.9` and `wi/wr = -0.33`

From the plot, if `z = 100` and `k = 2.5` : `wr = 1.087`; `wi/wr = -0.0013`. However via my code, I find : `wr = 1.4` and `wi/wr = -0.75`

Please, what I need to change or Specify more ?

Comment: A link to the paper? Maybe you have a typo?  I do notice that your integral gives convergence errors (which go away when you add a small imaginary part to the guess for `FindRoot`).  When I try to substitute the answers from the plot, `eq[1.138 - .0066 1.138 I, 3.0, 100.0]` I get an answer of `-1200.24 - 3.92757 I` and not `0`, so that isn't a root value

Comment: This is the link to the paper Plot : [link](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/544873Plot.png) and to the equation [link](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/618564Equation.png). µ in plot means z. The solid black line represents the exact values of my equation.

Comment: Sorry, this is the link to `gamma(nu)` [link](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/516301Equation2.png).

Comment: you didn't include a link to the paper.  The code looks like it does the equations correctly, although you could have written it **much** easier to compare, i.e. by defining functions for gamma, by using the same variable names, etc.  You didn't include a sigma in your code, can I then assume they use a value of 1 for sigma?

Comment: I am sorry. `sigma=1 if wi=0` and `sigma=2 if wi<0` and  `sigma=0 if wi>0`.

Comment: Okay - sorry, I don't see a mistake in the code so I'm not sure where to go with this.  Good luck to you

Comment: There are multiple roots and `FindRoot` will not necessarily find the one you have in mind: `In[957]:= 
wstart[k_, z_, start_] := w /. FindRoot[eq[w, k, z] == 0, {w, start}]
In[958]:= Table[
 wstart[3, 100, 
  start], {start, {1 + I, 1 - I, 1 + I/2, 1 - I/2, 3 + I, 
   3 - I, -1 + I, -1 - I}}]

Out[958]= {0.857357344272 + 1.02149783184 I, 
 1.05703820208 - 1.09750270086 I, 0.857357344272 + 1.02149783184 I, 
 2.21952029328*10^-21 - 0.800898057115 I, 
 2.94306970626 + 0.931916377491 I, 
 2.90898850745 - 0.964422306171 I, -0.857357344272 + 
  1.02149783184 I, -1.05703820208 - 1.09750270086 I}`.